# How can I automatically http POST many files sequentially with a break?

Tags: linux, testing, post, http-post, system-testing

for manual testing I want to send multiply files to my local server.

At the moment I'm using the firefox extension Poster. But it is a hassle, if you like me have some hundreds files and have to select every single file and post.

I want to send each file post automatically, with let's say a break of 5 seconds.

Is there a tool for that?

Using Linux x64 (xubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a simple command line like

```
for file in *.txt; do POST http://host.domain.com < "$file"; sleep 5; done
```

The `POST` utility comes from the Ubuntu package `libwww-perl` but of course there are dozens of similar command line utilities which offer POSTing of contents to a given URL (`wget`, `curl`, …).

Answer (score 0):

Use curl:

```
curl -X POST --form "fileupload=@filename.txt" http://your_url.com
```

insert this code inside 5 sec loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use "wget" utility and made script which will execute wget every 5 seconds with different file